# Classification / prediction of multiple time series

Tags: r, time-series, python

I have a multiple-time series problem. I have a dataframe with regions in columns and dates in rows (which represents the week of the year). Each value is **the number of events that occurred in that week for that region.**

- I would like to classify if yes/no in the following (next) week, an event will occur in a given region (the probability, as in the case of a supervised classification)
- For the regions where it is yes, that there will be an enumeration the following (next) week, predict the number of events that will be used.

[image]

```python
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2000-01', 0, 0, 1, 3], 
    ['2000-03', 0, 1, 0, 5], 
    ['2000-09', 0, 2, 0, 0],
    ['2000-14', 0, 0, 0, 1], 
    ['2000-15', 1, 1, 0, 2], 
    ['2000-18', 0, 2, 0, 3],
    ['2000-20', 3, 1, 2, 0], 
    ['2000-21', 0, 1,10, 5], 
    ['2000-22', 0, 3, 3, 4],
    ['2000-23', 15, 0, 0, 5], 
    ['2000-35', 0, 1, 5, 3], 
    ['2000-42', 12, 15, 2, 4]
], columns =['week_yr', 'Region_a', 'Region_b', 'Region_c', 'Region_d'])
```

If possible an example of an application in python or r

Thanks

The same question and discussed here: [Time series: probability to exceed a certain threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189332/time-series-probability-to-exceed-a-certain-threshold) by @Paolo and @IrishStat

Comment: Does your actual data have massive gaps in the week year like the example?

Comment: No, I made it regular the time. So we don't have week jumps anymore.